# Are Midi-chlorians Ever Shown to Act Intelligently?

Tags: star-wars

In the [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page), the [midi-chlorian entry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian), under the heading **Biology** it states:

> Midi-chlorians were intelligent microscopic life-forms that served as organelles within all living cells, existing in a symbiotic relationship with the beings they inhabited and comprising a collective consciousness amongst themselves.

I've seen this referenced elsewhere, but don't know where it came from in Star Wars canon.  It seems to be quite important that midi-chlorians are intelligent, but there's nothing in the article or elsewhere that I've read or seen that shows there's any kind of intelligent behavior from midi-chlorians.

Is this just something that's been stated and not used, or are there instances in stories showing intelligent behavior or even something as exotic as communication between "regular" characters and midi-chlorians?  If they're intelligent, couldn't they tell why someone was using the Force and refuse to act if it was something they didn't want to do?

Comment: They picked Hayden Christensen. If that's not a sign of lack of intelligence, I don't know what is.

Comment: They were smart enough to keep well out of the way in the sequel trilogy.

Comment: They were a mistake.........JarJar level mistake.....period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qui-Gon claims that it was the midi-chlorians themselves, presumably acting intelligently, that made Shmi conceive Anakin in order to bring balance to the Force.

Comment: But Sith lore says that was the work of Darth Plagueis, who had learned to manipulate them to create life.

Comment: Which set in train the sequence of events which led to episodes I, II & III. Question is whether that demonstrated *intelligence*... :)

Answer (score 1):

Since The Force is created by Midichlorians, and the Force sometimes **guides** Jedi, that means they posess (at least as a group) a certain level of intelligence.

Comment: It could also be like the flow of a river, that they're just tuned in to the Force and move with currents in it, like a floating starfish.

Comment: @TangoOversway - I distinctly recall the inferences of "intelligent guidance". But don't have any specific quotes in mind now.

Comment: I'd love it if you can find them.  I think Lucas and EU writers may like the idea of the collective intelligence, but have just never figured out what they can do with it.  (I'd like to see a story where someone communicates with midi-chlorians!)

Comment: @TangoOversway - It was more the old stuff... I'm tempted to say Yodayish from ESB