# Was Darth Sidious aware of Anakin prior to the Jedi picking him up?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-phantom-menace

Episodes I through III of *Star Wars* detail the life of Anakin Skywalker, including his manipulation at the hands of Darth Sidious. Since Anakin was apparently a side effect of work done by Darth Sidious' master, [Darth Plagueis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9714/1234), was Darth Sidious aware of Anakin's existence when he still lived on Tatooine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

From the plot summary of *[Star Wars : Darth Plagueis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis)* novel on Wookieepedia:

> As the novel comes to a close during the events of *The Phantom Menace*, **Sidious and Plagueis learn that a young boy named Anakin Skywalker, a former slave found by Qui-Gon Jinn on Tatooine, had been born of the Force.** They discern that this is most likely due to Plagueis's experiment of creating life through the Force that he had commenced about a decade earlier.